# How can I access a property dynamically by name without using reflection?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, dynamic, properties

At first I was using:

```
sortedList = unsorted.AsParallel().OrderBy(myItem => TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(myItem)[firstSort.Item2].GetValue(myItem));
```

Where firstSort.Item2 was the string name of the property.  However, the performance degraded significantly as the number of items in the unsorted list increased. (As I expected)

Is there a way to do this without using reflection?

The brute force approach would be to do something like:

```
if(firstSort.Item2 == "Size")
   sortedList = unsorted.AsParallel().OrderBy(myItem => myItem.Size);
else if(firstSort.Item2 == "Price")
   sortedList = unsorted.AsParallel().OrderBy(myItem => myItem.Price);
...
```

I'm looking for something that would accomplish the above behavior, but without having to hardcode in all the different properties in the interface.

Comment: have you tried using TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(myItem)[firstSort.Item2].GetValue(myItem) out of the OrderBy and after using it in order by?

Comment: How much faster is you 2nd solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can [use `Expression<T>` to pre-compile](http://www.infoq.com/articles/expression-compiler) the expressions that you're passing to `OrderBy`. Then you can look them up at runtime.

Comment: I'm thinking this might give me the best result for my scenario.  Looking into it now.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you use that doesn't involve a hard-coded list of actual properties, will be using Reflection "behind the scenes".

Comment: Yes, but I just don't want to have to reflect every time I access the property.  Is there a way I can determine which property to access using reflection and then have it sort on that without having to GetValue every time?

Comment: @Chris: GetValue is how you get the value of the property. Since it's different for each object, you have to call it for each object.

Comment: OK, I guess I should clarify...How can I minimize the performance hit from using reflection.

Comment: is performance an *actual* issue?  or is it a *perceived* issue?  have you profiled it?

Comment: Absolutely! List gets up to 10M items...reflection access is the hot path with this sort.

Comment: GetValue is 81.8% of the CPU time spent in the sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the PropertyInfo once and use it to call GetValue over multiple target objects.  This will be much less expensive than calling TypeDescriptor.GetProperties for every item in the list.

Also, try removing AsParallel - the overhead may actually be reducing performance rather than helping it in this case.

Try this:

```
var prop = unsorted.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperty(firstSort.Item2);
sortedList = unsorted.OrderBy(myItem => prop.GetValue(myItem, null));
```

Comment: I tried this...there was a small performance improvement, but still pretty slow.  The AsParallel is definitely worth it though.  With >1M items in the list, I get 2-5X speedup.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) in your class, then you can avoid the reflection when using TypeDescriptor.

Of course, I'm assuming you own the type of `myItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the Dynamic LINQ library provided by Microsoft.

Here is a link: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I like Roger's answer the best for a true solution, but if you want something simple, you can build a small code generator to take the class and break out its properties into a dictionary of string to lambda, representing each property. At runtime, you could call from this dictionary to retrieve the appropriate lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DLR. The open source framework [Impromptu-Interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface) does all the dlr plumbing behind the scenes and and gets the value of a property [2.5x faster than reflection](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#dynamic_Impromptu.InvokeGet%28object_target,_String_Or_InvokeMembe).

```
sortedList = unsorted.AsParallel().OrderBy(myItem => Impromptu.InvokeGet(myItem,firstSort.Item2));
```